# VIM under Cygwin some characters missing

Tags: encoding, cygwin

Just installed vim and vimified plugin set under cygwin. Everything works like a charm except one annoying issue - i can see some special symbols (like new line) and it seems that some characters are shown in wrong way, for example the automatically inserted by VIM newline symbol is replaced with a box.
I am using mintty, the locale is en_US.UTF8, the same is listed under mintty configuration.

Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: What do you expect to see?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Not a box, i expect to see a "-" or another meaningful symbol.

Comment: The first character is defined with the `showbreak` option and the last one is defined with `listchars`. See `:help 'showbreak'` and `:help listchars'`. What is the output of `:set encoding`?

Comment: Thank you! The output of encoding is `encoding=utf-8`. Thank you, i replaced showbreak symbol. But regarding lcs-eol, it seems that there is no command to null this setting, only one way to do this is to redefine the eol symbol.

Comment: `:set nolist` :P

Comment: I have set encoding, fileencoding, termencoding to utf-8. Facing similar issue. Some complex unicode characters arent shown properly. How to fix it?